# ClickOnce installer .exe to MSI converter

Tags: windows-installer, clickonce, exe

I have a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) deployment package (.exe). If I convert this EXE file to [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer), will that effect the ClickOnce deployment functionalities like automatic updates?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384248.aspx) correctly, the deployment package is used to install the deployment into a central location from which the actual ClickOnce installation is performed.

For example, when you have a customer which does not allow you to publish your ClickOnce application and updates remotely, you can send him a deployment package, which he executes to install copy the deployment to a location he chooses. From there he'd perform ClickOnce installations as usual.

Putting a newer version to the location would then cause the installed clients to perform an update as usual.

We do this sometimes when deploying remotely through VS2010 fails: We deploy to `C:\Temp` for example and then send the files and subfolders to the customer for him to copy them to the location. Only we're sending a ZIP file and you're creating an installer that does things automatically.